# Are there any side effect of using -preset ultrafast in FFMPEG command?

Tags: ffmpeg

I using the following command to add text watermark in a video file:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=text='© Krishna':x=(main_w-text_w-10):y=(main_h-text_h-10):fontsize=32:fontcolor=black:box=1:boxcolor=white@0.5: boxborderw=5" -preset ultrafast output.mp4
```

Is there any repercussion of using the

> "-preset ultrafast"

filter?

Comment: Larger file size. `-preset veryfast` is still fast enough but will give smaller file size.

Comment: @Gyan Okay, but does it reduce the video quality?

Comment: Not really.....

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the ffmpeg wiki:

> A preset is a collection of options that will provide a certain encoding speed to compression ratio. A slower preset will provide better compression (compression is quality per filesize). This means that, for example, if you target a certain file size or constant bit rate, you will achieve better quality with a slower preset. Similarly, for constant quality encoding, you will simply save bitrate by choosing a slower preset.

So the presets specify an ”effort” constraint, and hence an encoding time and space constraint. And whether it affects your quality, depends on if you also specified a bitrate constraint or a quality constraint.

**If you specified a quality constraint only**, the presets are to be treated like in any other generic file compression program. They only influence, how much CPU time and RAM space ffmpeg is going to put into getting the file as small as possible for the given quality, and not related to the actual quality setting. (E.g. if you specified lossless quality, it will always be lossless.)

**If you specified a bitrate only**, of course it will have to obey that, even if it does not have enough time to get the file smaller. So **it will drop the only thing it can: The quality.**

**If you specify neither**, it will set your quality to the codec’s default (e.g. `CRF-28.0` for `lib265`) and not constrain the bitrate. **So you can be certain to not lose any quality from specifying `ultrafast`.**

I do not know what happens, if you specify both. It will probably warn you.

Comment: P.S.: Fun fact: In my current test case, of a 1s 60fps HEVC video from JPEGs,  `ultrafast` actually produces a 10% *smaller* file than `veryslow`, and 20% smaller than `veryfast`. ;) … Showing that `ultrafast` clearly leaves out more complex data structures that are useful for compressing larger files.